# Solr DataImportHandler doesn't recognize special command like $skipDoc, why?

Tags: solr

I'm trying to figure out why the hell this configuration doesnt recognize special command `$skipDoc` and `$skipRow`, but truly don't know what's wrong, i'm using solr 4.0:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<dataConfig>
<dataSource type="JdbcDataSource" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db" user="root" password=""/>
    <document>
        <entity name="item" query="SELECT * FROM description">
             <field column="id" name="id" />
         <field column="$skipDoc"  regex=".*" replaceWith="true" sourceColName="title"/>
        </entity>
    </document>
</dataConfig>
```

I cut unneeded field to leave the example simple but mostly this's the configuration.

What the developers of solr have made that didn't wrote in the docs to start magically using this command? Or the beast is me?

---

The beast is me, as aserba toll me i need add transformer="RegexTransformer" to each entity that have a field modified by a regular expression, in this example we need to have it:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<dataConfig>
<dataSource type="JdbcDataSource" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db" user="root" password=""/>
    <document>
        <entity name="item" transformer="RegexTransformer" query="SELECT * FROM description">
             <field column="id" name="id" />
         <field column="$skipDoc"  regex=".*" replaceWith="true" sourceColName="title"/>
        </entity>
    </document>
</dataConfig>
```

Hope help to other one was a headache for me.

Answer (score 0):

How about trying `<field column="${skipDoc}"  regex=".*" replaceWith="true" sourceColName="title"/>`